# Factors have different levels but I don't understand why

Tags: r, r-factor

I'm using a Bradley-Terry model to model the outcome of tennis matches, and have encountered the following error. When I run:

```
library(BradleyTerry2)

matches <- read.csv("data/matches.csv")
model <- BTm(cbind(wins1,
                   wins2),
             player1, player2, data=matches)
model
```

I get the error message:

```
Error in Diff(player1, player2, formula, id, data, separate.ability, refcat,  : 
  'player1$..' and 'player2$..' must be factors with the same levels
```

The dataframe 'matches' has this format (Small reproducible example).

| player1 | player2 | wins1 | wins2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Agassi | Federer | 0 | 6 |
| Agassi | Hewitt | 1 | 0 |
| Agassi | Roddick | 1 | 0 |
| Federer | Henman | 3 | 1 |
| Federer | Hewitt | 9 | 0 |
| Federer | Roddick | 5 | 0 |
| Henman | Hewitt | 0 | 2 |
| Henman | Roddick | 1 | 1 |
| Hewitt | Roddick | 3 | 2 |

... and so on. Any name that appears in player1 will appear in player2.

I don't understand why the factors player1 and player2 have different levels? I've tried setting them to factors using `as.factor`, but that didn't work. I also tried removing `data=matches` and using `matches$wins1` etc. as arguments to the `BTm` function but that also didn't work. Now I'm a bit stuck, so any ideas are welcome!! Thank you :)

Comment: perhaps there's a player in the dataset who only appears once? Consider making the levels to both a combined vector of the unique names from both

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. In your example "Roger Federer" is in player1 but not player2 which would cause a problem.

Comment: check `levels(df$player1)` and `levels(df$player2)`. Maybe you can just convert to character and it will just work, or make a union of these levels and use `factor()` with the levels arg on both of these variables

Comment: Can you include the output from `levels(matches$player1)` and `levels(matches$player2)`?  Also, does that function require them to have the same levels in the same order?

Comment: @PGSA yes it looks like the levels() of each of them are different, so I'd imagine there's a bug in my code used to generate the data file. I'll have a look at that!

Answer (score 0):

Look at what you have in the 1st and 2nd columns.
Factors are internally coded as consecutive integers starting at 1. Below I `unclass` each of them in order to get their internal representation.

- `player1` has two values, 1 and 2;
- `player2` has two values, 1 and 2;
- in `player1` the level `"Rafael Nadal"` is the 1st, its value is **1**;
- but in `player2` the level `"Rafael Nadal"` is the 2nd, its value is **2**.

This is because each of the columns is a factor on its own, with no relation to the other column.

```r
lapply(matches[1:2], unclass)
#> $player1
#> [1] 2 2 1
#> attr(,"levels")
#> [1] "Rafael Nadal"  "Roger Federer"
#> 
#> $player2
#> [1] 2 1 1
#> attr(,"levels")
#> [1] "Andy Murray"  "Rafael Nadal"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-14</sup>

The solution is to get all of the unique values of all columns and use those unique values as levels **when creating the factor**.

In the code that follows the first instruction gets all unique values as character strings. Then creates factor columns with those strings as their levels.

```r
lvls <- matches[1:2] |> unlist() |> as.character() |> unique()
matches[1:2] <- lapply(matches[1:2], factor, levels = lvls)

# check that now "Rafael Nadal" is always value 2
lapply(matches[1:2], unclass)
#> $player1
#> [1] 1 1 2
#> attr(,"levels")
#> [1] "Roger Federer" "Rafael Nadal"  "Andy Murray"  
#> 
#> $player2
#> [1] 2 3 3
#> attr(,"levels")
#> [1] "Roger Federer" "Rafael Nadal"  "Andy Murray"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-14</sup>

---

## Data

```r
matches <- structure(list(
  player1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("Rafael Nadal", "Roger Federer"), class = "factor"), 
  player2 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Andy Murray", "Rafael Nadal"), class = "factor"), 
  wins1 = c(3L, 5L, 4L), wins2 = c(2L, 2L, 3L)), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-14</sup>

---

## Edit

In the mean time the example data set in the question has changed. Except for references to the players names the code above is still valid and solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With great help from the comments on the original post it has now been solved... Just needed to make sure that the players1 and players2 columns contain only the same players (this might mean switching some round in the data file), and then using `as.factor()` around `player1` and `player2`.